# Are human teeth only diphyodont or both diphyodont and monodont?

Tags: human-biology

Many books say human teeth are only diphyodont .But premolars appear only once and one molar appears later which should be considered monophyodont.
 Dental Formulae :

CHILD -
 1. Incissor -2/2
 2. Canine -1/1
 3. Premolar-0/0
 4. Molar-2/2
ADULT-
 1. Incissor-2/2
2.Canine-1/1
3.Premolar-2/2
4.Molar 3/3 .

Here the 3rd molar and two premolar appear only once. Therefore human teeth should be both diphyodont and monophyodont

Comment: I wrote the dental formula for child and adult..

Answer (score 2):

The definitions from the [Oxford Dictionary of Dentistry](http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780199533015.001.0001/acref-9780199533015):

**Diphyodont**

> Describing the development of two successive dentitions, one primary
>   and another secondary (permanent), as found in most mammals including
>   humans.

**Monophyodont**

> Possessing only one generation of teeth. It is a characteristic of
>   some mammals, including the manatee, seal, and walrus.

As you can see, the term diphyodont is generally not used to refer to the individual teeth, but rather to the whole animal (i.e. the sets of teeth). A monophyodont is an animal that has only one set of teeth.